# Azure BLOB upload Task VS 2015 - Issue

Tags: visual-studio, azure, ssis, blob, storage

I am using VS 2015 to upload files to Azure storage account. I

1. Selected the integration services project.
2. Dragged and dropped the "Azure BLOB upload task"
3. Provided the necessary connection info(Account name, access keys, container name etc) to azure storage account.
4. Double checked the "Test connection" and ensured it returned Success.
5. Ran the package and it fails with the message below.

What am I missing? The message is generic (to me). Any help is highly appreciated.

```
SSIS package "C:\SSISProjects\POC\BlobExportToAzureStorage\BlobExportToAzureStorage\Package.dtsx" starting.
Error: 0xC0010026 at Azure Blob Upload Task: The task has failed to load. The contact information for this task is "Azure Blob Upload Task; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved".
Error: 0xC0024107 at Azure Blob Upload Task: There were errors during task validation.
SSIS package "C:\SSISProjects\POC\BlobExportToAzureStorage\BlobExportToAzureStorage\Package.dtsx" finished: Success.
The program '[8436] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit  Tonechas!!